# How to scrape the second last anchor link in Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

So I wrote a code to scrape the parent of the current category from a breadcrumb:

```
node_parent = @data.at_css(".bc a:nth-child(2)").text unless @data.at_css(".bc a:nth-child(2)").nil?
```

The code says: scrape the second last anchor link. Here's the structure of the HTML:

```
<span class="bc">
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <span class="d">></span>
  <img src="" />
  <a href="/us/Apparel/1036682"">Apparel</a>
  <div class="node"></div>
  <a href="">...</a>
  <span class="d">></span>
  Baby
</span>
```

So in this case the code will scrape `Apparel`

The problem is that the code will fail in situations like this:

```
<span class="bc">
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <span class="d">></span>
  <img src="" />
  Apparel
</span>
```

Since there isn't a second last anchor link.

What's a better solution to this?

Live example of the pages:

http://www.findbrowsenodes.com/us/Apparel/1036682
http://www.findbrowsenodes.com/us/Apparel/2402554011

Comment: so if there is only one single `<a>`, you want to grab it or ignore it ?

Comment: @Babai I still want to green it (in my example: "Home")

Answer (score 1):

Before going to answer your question,I took a similar example *html* as below :-

```html
<span class="bc">
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">foo</a>
</span>
<span class="bc">
  <a href="">Home</a>
</span>
<span class="bc">
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">bax</a>
  <a href="">baz</a>
</span>
```

**Xpath:-**

```xpath
 //span[@class='bc'][count(./a)>1]/a[count(following-sibling::a)=1]
```

**Output:-**

```html
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">bax</a>
```

**Nokogiri**

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-eotl
<span class="bc">
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <span class="d">></span>
  <img src="" />
  <a href="/us/Apparel/1036682">Apparel</a>
  <div class="node"></div>
  <a href="">...</a>
  <span class="d">></span>
  Baby
</span>
<span class="bc">
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <span class="d">></span>
  <img src="" />
  Apparel
</span>
   eotl

doc.xpath("//span[@class='bc'][count(./a)>1]/a[count(following-sibling::a)=1]").map(&:text)
# => ["Apparel"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
anchors = doc.css('a')
second_last_anchor = (anchors.length >= 2) ? anchors[-2] : anchors[0]
```

This basically gets all the links in the doc. If there are 2 or more links, return the second last one, which is the `[-2]` index. If there is only 1 link, it will return the one. Otherwise, if there are no links, it will return nil.

`doc` was the entire html page, but you can use whatever specific node you want to check.